# Как задается поведение интерфейсам?

Tags: java, интерфейс

Почему при имплементировании некоторых интерфейсов они обладают уже неким поведением? Например `MouseListener`, `ActionListener`, `KeyListener`, большинство функциональных интерфейсов и т.д, хотя в декларации у них нет тела метода.

Comment: Если правильно понял вопрос, то возможно интерфейс наследуется от другого, который содержит эти методы.

Comment: Пример бы. Какие конкретно интерфейсы? `Mouse`, `Action`, `KeyListener` - довольно распространенные интерфейсы из разных библиотек. Необходимо уточнение.

Comment: java.awt.event.*

Comment: вы не путаете интерфейсы и абстрактные классы?